# Minix 3.2 Kernel Call to access on CPU registers

Tags: kernel, cpu, minix

I am minix developer beginner. I want to work on the MCE (machine check Exception) in minix. I read and applied the tutorials to make system calls and kernel calls but so far I haven't encountered any documentation on kernel calls that read information to a specific registry address. I need your help to advance my research.